# Automating slicing prodcedures using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently using Pandas and Python to handle much of the repetitive tasks, I need done for my master thesis. At this point, I have written some code (with help from stack overflow) that, based on some event dates in one file, finds a start and end date to use as a date range in another file. These dates are then located and appended to an empty list, which I can then output to excel. However, using the below code I get a dataframe with 5 columns and 400.000 + rows (which is basically what I want), but not how I want the data outputted to excel. Below is my code:

```
end_date = pd.DataFrame(data=(df_sample['Date']-pd.DateOffset(days=2)))
start_date = pd.DataFrame(data=(df_sample['Date']-pd.offsets.BDay(n=252)))

merged_dates = pd.merge(end_date,start_date,left_index=True,right_index=True)

ff_factors = []

for index, row in merged_dates.iterrows():
    time_range= (df['Date'] > row['Date_y']) & (df['Date'] <= row['Date_x'])
    df_factor = df.loc[time_range]
    ff_factors.append(df_factor)

appended_data = pd.concat(ff_factors, axis=0)
```

I need the data to be 5 columns and 250 rows (columns are variable identifiers) side by side, so that when outputting it to excel I have, for example column A-D and then 250 rows for each column. This then needs to be repeated for column E-H and so on. Using iloc, I can locate the 250 observations using `appended_data.iloc[0:250]`, with both 5 columns and 250 rows, and then output it to excel.

Are the any way for me to automate the process, so that after selecting the first 250 and outputting it to excel, it selects the next 250 and outputs it next to the first 250 and so on?

I hope the above is precise and clear, else I'm happy to elaborate!

EDIT:

[image: My entire dataframe]

The above picture illustrate what I get when outputting to excel; 5 columns and 407.764 rows. What I needed is to get this split up into the following way:
[image: Using iloc[0:250] on the entire smaple]

The second picture illustrates how I needed the total sample to be split up. The first five columns and corresponding 250 rows needs to be as the second picture. When I do the next split using iloc[250:500], I will get the next 250 rows, which needs to be added after the initial five columns and so on.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly you want to end up with a single excel sheet that has 250 rows and 1600-ish columns?

Comment: Basically yes, it would be around 8000 ish columns, and 250 rows for each column. The first 5 columns im describing relates to a single date/observation, thus the total amount of columns should be around 8000.

Comment: Could you edit in a sized-down version of what you're looking for? Say a 3 column, 20 row 'before' df and a 15 column, 4 row 'after' df?

Comment: @EFT Sure thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `np.reshape`, which can be made to behave as desired on individual columns, and which should be much faster than a loop through the rows, and `pd.concat`, to join the dataframes it makes back together:

```
def reshape_appended(df, target_rows, pad=4):
    df = df.copy()  # don't modify in-place
    # below line adds strings, '0000',...,'0004' to the column names
    # this ensures sorting the columns preserves the order
    df.columns = [str(i).zfill(pad)+df.columns[i] for i in range(len(df.columns))]
    #target number of new columns per column in df
    target_cols = len(df.index)//target_rows
    last_group = pd.DataFrame()
    # below conditional fires if there will be leftover rows - % is mod
    if len(df.index)%target_rows != 0:
        last_group = df.iloc[-(len(df.index)%target_rows):].reset_index(drop=True)
        df = df.iloc[:-(len(df.index)%target_rows)]  # keep rows that divide nicely
    #this is a large list comprehension, that I'll elaborate on below
    groups = [pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.reshape((target_rows, target_cols),
                                                  order='F'),
                           columns=[str(i).zfill(pad)+col for i in range(target_cols)])
              for col in df.columns]
    if not last_group.empty:  # if there are leftover rows, add them back 
        last_group.columns = [pad*'9'+col for col in last_group.columns]
        groups.append(last_group)
    out = pd.concat(groups, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
    out.columns = out.columns.str[2*pad:]  # remove the extra characters in the column names
    return out
```

`last_group` takes care of any rows that don't divide evenly into sets of 250. The playing around with column names enforces proper sorting order.

```
df[col].values.reshape((target_rows, target_cols), order='F')
```

Reshapes the values in the column `col` of `df` into the shape specified by the tuple `(target_rows, target_cols)`, with the ordering Fortran uses, indicated by `F`.

```
columns=[str(i).zfill(pad)+col for i in range(target_cols)]
```

is just giving names to these columns, with any eye to establishing proper ordering afterward.

Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (23, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

reshape_appended(df, 5)
Out[160]: 
   a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c    a    b    c
0  8  3  0  4  1  9  5  4  7  2  3  4  5.0  7.0  2.0
1  1  6  1  3  5  1  1  6  0  5  9  4  6.0  0.0  1.0
2  3  1  3  4  3  8  9  3  9  8  7  8  7.0  3.0  2.0
3  4  0  1  5  5  6  6  4  4  0  0  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  9  7  3  5  7  4  6  5  8  9  5  5  NaN  NaN  NaN

df
Out[161]: 
    a  b  c
0   8  3  0
1   1  6  1
2   3  1  3
3   4  0  1
4   9  7  3
5   4  1  9
6   3  5  1
7   4  3  8
8   5  5  6
9   5  7  4
10  5  4  7
11  1  6  0
12  9  3  9
13  6  4  4
14  6  5  8
15  2  3  4
16  5  9  4
17  8  7  8
18  0  0  3
19  9  5  5
20  5  7  2
21  6  0  1
22  7  3  2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @EFT. As im still learning Python and Pandas, this looks a bit complicated to me. I will have to play around with it, to understand what's going on. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @MBV_DK I'll add comments.

Comment: I have been playing around with the function a bit now, and I keep getting a ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 14 into shape (250,1631), after running reshape_appended(appended_data, 250, pad=4). Can this be due to the total size of appended_data? e.g the total number of rows not being evenly divided by 250?

Comment: @MBV_DK - that would be because I goofed on colon placement in the version I posted, thereby scrapping the part that was divisible, instead of the remainder. I've actually checked the function as a whole now, caught a few more errors that come from pasting snippets from the console together into a function, and it now works for me.

Comment: It works now! Thank you and a big high five, you saved me a lot of work @EFT

Answer (score 0):

My best guess to solving the problem would be to try and loop, until the counter is greater than length, so

```
i = 250 # counter
j = 0 # left limit

for x in range(len("your dataframe")): 
    appended_data.iloc[j:i]
    i+=250
    if i > len("your df"):
        appended_data.iloc[j:(len("your df"))
        break
    else:
        j = i
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed! I looks like what I am looking for. I have a question, when you write "your dataframe" are you refering to a new dataframe?

Comment: No it's the one you already have made, I just kept forgetting its name so I wrote that :)

Comment: Oh okay! It because you're referring to appended_data on the iloc method, which is the dataframe currently holding all of the data :)

Comment: Ok, then just use the length of rows for that element and you should be good, just be sure not to change it's length inside your for loop